# Excel vba Function:filtering

Tags: vba, function

I am trying to write an excel function that will output a range containing a subset of values based on a value range and a filter range and a criteria.
Using the example below, I want to pass Range("A2:A5") and  Range("B2:B5") to output Range("C2:C5")

+---+-------+-------+-------+

|   |   A   |   B   |   C   |

+---+-------+-------+-------+

| 1 | Name  | Group | Output|

| 2 | Nick  | A     |  Nick |

| 3 | Marc  | A     | Marc  |

| 4 | Manny | B     | Luck  |

| 5 | Luck  | A     |       |

+---+-------+-------+-------+

I have written the code below so far. it works fine in vba but not when I call the function within the sheet
D1.function -> =filterFN(A2:A6,B2:B6,D1,"B")

:

```
Sub test()
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D1") = filterFN(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A6"), Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1:B6"), Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D1"), "B")
End Sub

Function filterFN(valueRange As Range, filterRange As Range, outputRange As Range, criteriaStr As String)

    Dim Arr1() As Variant ' declare an unallocated array.
    Dim Arr2() As Variant
    Dim Arr3(50) As Variant

    Dim i, j As Integer

    Arr1 = valueRange
    Arr2 = filterRange

    For i = 1 To UBound(Arr1, 1)
        If Arr2(i, 1) = criteriaStr Then
            Arr3(j) = Arr1(i, 1)
            j = j + 1
        End If

    Next i

    [outputRange].Resize(UBound(Arr3)) = Application.Transpose(Arr3)
    filterFN = Arr3(0)

End Function
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use a function called from a worksheet to update that worksheet (or another sheet): all you can do is return a value to the calling cell(s)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170787

Comment: Hello, I know its possible to do this with an array formula but my problem is that my workbook is already very large. I am trying to find an optimized a solution so I dont crash my spreadsheet.